# aws s3 - upload a directory and its subdirectories as a s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-athena

I try  to transfer a directory and its sub-directories to an s3 bucket by code. 
In my case a sub-directory is a partition in the bucket.
As in the picture: 
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The structure given in the picture is in my OS (linux), Can I transfer this structure to an aws s3 bucket by code; all the structure (with sub-direcories also)

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to upload your directory structure to s3?

Then you can try this with the CLI:

```
aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

You could also achieve this programatically:

```
TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
MultipleFileUpload upload = tm.uploadDirectory(bucket, folder, new File(filePath), true);

try
{
    // Or you can block and wait for the upload to finish
    upload.waitForCompletion();
    LOGGER.debug("Upload complete.", bucket, folder);
}
catch (AmazonClientException amazonClientException)
{
    LOGGER.error("Unable to upload file, upload was aborted.", amazonClientException);
    throw amazonClientException;
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html